# White guitar turned yellow

Tags: electric-guitar

Im not sure if this is necessarily the right place for this but i figured someone might have had a similar issue. I have a Yamaha RGX A2 in white but over time its turned yellow. I assume its the clearcoat rather than the actual colour underneath. Is there a way to reverse this?

Comment: I wouldn't even try. It's not an expensive guitar, but ruining the paintwork isn't going to improve its value or endear it more to anyone. I've a 70's Rikki that I affectionately call 'tobacco white'.. meaning it's about a mid-beige/yellow these days.

Comment: There will be a way, but it'll cost more than the guitar is worth, and probably will go the same way in the future. It's called *patina*.

Comment: _Patina_, an elegant for for _rust!_ :-)

Answer (score 3):

Everyone has a right to their own preferences, but the music store that I worked at just loved to see those older guitars with a yellowed finish come into the store in trade for the shiny new guitars. Many customers would choose the older, yellowed, heavily played instruments over the shiny new guitars sometimes at higher prices. There seems to be a certain mystique about aged instruments, but it seems they need to show their age to be desirable. Go figure.

Comment: With very rare exceptions, I have always preferred buying good used guitars. And it's not about esthetics. If they have been kept and used well, if they have aged and settled well, they beat any new guitar any day of the week, at least for me.

Comment: You buy a vintage guitar for the oldness of the wood, but be sure the quality of electric guitar production has improved greatly over the years. There is also the issue of certain era of pickups cannot be reproduced because of environmental concerns in the manufacturing process. Also a lot of big manufacturers had eras where they had slumps. CBS era fenders and 90s Gibson are guitars I would avoid. You cannot think it is good just because it is old

Comment: @Neil Meyer- Your final sentence is very true, but many folks don't seem to understand and make purchases based on patina. As I stated before, Go figure.

Comment: It is actually also worth noting that the PRS led 90's rock scene was greatly inspired by the poor quality of gibson guitars at the time. Would a band like Collective Soul have played a PRS in the 90's if Gibson had there act together? I wonder!

Comment: But still look at this and say to me that the guitar does not get your motor running - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E9nFP-p_TZE&ab_channel=NormansRareGuitarsNormansRareGuitars

Answer (score 0):

I am not a chemist, but I believe this can be an effect from sun exposure. Something about UV rays can cause it to turn yellow. Possibly by Lessing the whitening agents in the paint (titanium dioxide?). However, polyurethane also yellows over time, which, like you, I'm guessing is the culprit. It is possible to sand off the outer layer, and recoat it, but like others have said: it might not work, and the yellowing is cool.